# How to get RStudio to automatically compile R Markdown Vignettes?

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio, r-markdown

I am trying to write R Package vignettes using R Markdown. I am using R Studio's package authoring tools.

I have R greater than version 3.0.

I have an .Rmd file in the `vignettes` folder that contains the following text at the top:

```
<!--
%\VignetteEngine{knitr::knitr}
%\VignetteIndexEntry{An Introduction to the bootcorrelations package}
-->
```

I have the following in my `DESCRIPTION` file:

```
VignetteBuilder: knitr
Suggests: knitr
```

When I clean and build or build and reload the package in RStudio, the vignette source is displayed, but not the HTML (i.e., there's no HTML file in `inst/man`).

[image]

**How can I get RStudio to automatically create the HTML from an R Markdown Vignette?**

I've read through [Yihui's post on R Package Vignettes with Markdown](http://yihui.name/en/2012/09/r-package-markdown-vignettes/) and it suggests using a makefile, but this more recent [documentation about knitr vignettes](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/vignette/) suggests that the makefile is no longer required.

I also realise that I could manually create the HTML vignette with a command like this:

```
library(knitr)
knit(input='vignettes/foo.Rmd', output='inst/doc/foo.md')
library(markdown)
markdownToHTML('inst/doc/foo.md', 'inst/doc/foo.html')
```

---

A reproducible example:

````
Vectorize(dir.create)(c("test", "test/R", "test/man", "test/vignettes"))

cat(
  'Package: test
Title: Test pkg
Description: Investigate how to auto-compile markdown vignettes
Version: 0.0-1
Date: 2015-03-15
Author: Jeromy Anglim
Maintainer: Jeromy Anglim <a@b.com>
Suggests: knitr
License: Unlimited
VignetteBuilder: knitr',
  file = "test/DESCRIPTION"
)

cat(
  '---
title: "Introduction"
author: "Jeromy Anglim"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: html_document
---

<!--
%\\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
%\\VignetteIndexEntry{Introduction}
-->

# Introduction

A sample vignette!

```{r}
1 + 1
```',
  file = "test/vignettes/intro.Rmd"
)

cat(
  "#' Nothing
#' This function is only needed so that roxygen generates a NAMESPACE file.
#' @export
nothing <- function() 0",
  file = "test/R/nothing.R"
)

library(roxygen2)
library(devtools)

roxygenise("test")
build("test")
````

Comment: Why the need for the build to create the HTML?  Why not use knit HTML button instead if you're using R Studio?  It makes sense not to have the HTML as part of the build as it should be minimal and the vignette can then be created when installed.

Comment: @TylerRinker I take your point. Perhaps I need to think more about workflow. My initial motivations was: (a) to use the vignettes as an additional package test, (b) ensure the files are accessible on the github copy of the repository (e.g., use http://htmlpreview.github.com/ on the resulting html vigenette, which I can then link to from the `readme.md` file); (c) ensure that any copy of the vignette distributed as a raw file would be up to date.

Comment: I have similar needs and use a workflow that (1) use knit HTML (2) copy the file to a dropbox public folder with `file.copy` (3) use a link from the GitHub README to the dropbox file.  This works pretty well for me.  PS didn't know about the htmlpreview.github.com.  pretty cool.

Comment: I'm replacing step (2) with the htmlpreview.  Thanks.  Still leaves the question of why you'd want the build to make the Vignette.  You can even [style the vignette in RStudio](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/authoring/markdown_custom_rendering) if that's the reason and it's way faster than a complete build.  I think this workflow still accomplishes your 3 goals.

Comment: It is entirely possible to extend [`servr`](https://github.com/yihui/servr) a little bit so that it can serve package vignettes in the browser, and all you need to do is to refresh the page if you want to rebuild the vignette. I have written the code in my mind, and just need to find some time to type it out :)

Answer (score 17):

**Update:** Thinking laterally, there are at least three options.

#### 1. Use build_vignettes()

As @Hadley points out, running `build_vignettes()` from the `devtools` package will build vignettes and place them in the `inst/man` directory of the package.

```
devtools::build_vignettes()
```

Building the vignette means you get three versions in `inst/man`:

1. the Rmd source
2. the knitted or weaved HTML vignette
3. and the R code in the code blocks

This is not tied to the build and reload command in RStudio, but it is a one line solution to the task. And it could easily be incorporated into a `makefile`.

#### 2. Use `Knit HTML` in Rstudio

As @TylerRinker notes you can just use Knit HTML in Rstudio. This will add both md and HTML knitted versions of the rmd vignette to the `vignettes` directory.

This also is not tied to the build process but as @TylerRinker points out, often you don't want the vignettes tied to the main build process. This also has the benefit of giving you an md file which can be a nice option for displaying the vignette on github, although http://htmlpreview.github.com/ is an option for displaying HTML vignette on github.

#### 3. Build source package and extract from compressed file

`Build - Build Source Package` in RStudio  corresponds to `R CMD build`. When run a compressed `tar.gz` file is created which contains in the `inst/doc` directory the Rmd, R and HTML files for the original rmd vignette file.

This is described in the [official documentation on writing package vignettes](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Writing-package-vignettes) which instructs you to use `R CMD build` to generate PDF and HTML vignettes.

So it is possible to

1. Build Source
2. Unzip the tar.gz file
3. Browse and open the resulting file

Comment: You can use `devtools::build_vignettes()`

Comment: The only key is `R CMD build`; that is the official approach to getting compiled vignettes into the vignette index in the HTML help. Currently RStudio only does `R CMD INSTALL`, and I do not think that is always a good idea, e.g. it does not build vignettes. I'll mention it in the support forum if no one has done so.

Comment: Would you mind providing a sample make file that uses `build_vignettes()`?

Comment: Also @hadley, you have an ambiguous pronoun in the help documentation for `build_vignettes()`: which files are to be included in `.Rbuildignore`, the files in `vignettes/` or the files in `inst/doc/`?

Comment: So, I'm using RStudio version 0.98.836 and none of these options work. In particular, `build_vignettes()` returns `NULL` despite having a bonafide .Rmd in `vignettes/` and `knit HTML` doesn't save an .md or .html file in `vignettes/`... Any reason as to why this would be?