# R CMD build skips knitr/Rmd vignettes - "Output(s) listed in 'build/vignette.rds' but not in package"

Tags: r, knitr, cran, r-markdown

I have built an rmarkdown tutorial for an R package, and would like to include the compiled file when the package is built. Though the file compiles happily (including when I use `R CMD Sweave` to do so), I don't seem to be able to include it in a binary.

Specifically, when I run `R CMD BUILD` I get

```
* checking for file ‘./DESCRIPTION’ ... OK
[snip]
* installing the package to build vignettes
* creating vignettes ... OK
* checking for empty or unneeded directories
Removed empty directory ‘rentrez/inst/doc’
Removed empty directory ‘rentrez/inst’
Removed empty directory ‘rentrez/vignettes/assets’
Removed empty directory ‘rentrez/vignettes’
* building ‘rentrez_0.2.4.tar.gz’
```

But after installing this binary and running `vignette(package="rentrez")` there are no vignettes for the package.

So, what am I doing wrong?

If it helps, [this branch](https://github.com/ropensci/rentrez/tree/vignette) of the library contains the vignettes and associated edits to the package. The [file itself](https://github.com/ropensci/rentrez/blob/c6c7a8f9ab58010a9bfe224300df8abeff11030d/vignettes/rentrez_vignette.Rmd) is in `vignettes/` directory and starts with

```
<!--
%\VignetteEngine{knitr::knitr}
%\VignetteIndexEntry{rentrez tutorial}
-->
```

The [DESCRIPTION](https://github.com/ropensci/rentrez/blob/c6c7a8f9ab58010a9bfe224300df8abeff11030d/DESCRIPTION) file includes these lines

```
Suggests:
    testthat,-
VignetteBuilder: knitr
```

**EDIT**

I should have thought to run `R CMD CHECK` on the built package:

```
Output(s) listed in 'build/vignette.rds' but not in package:
  ‘inst/doc/rentrez_vignette.html’
```

As far as I can tell, `build/vignette.rds` is created by `R CMD BUILD`, but I don't why it points to `inst/doc` (even if this dir is deleted before the package is built)

Comment: For others browsing here, this might be another useful discussion to read: [How to get RStudio to automatically compile R Markdown Vignettes?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19372260/320399)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you have `rentrez_*` in your `.Rbuildignore` and that matches the name of your vignette. Lines in `.Rbuildignore` should look like

```
^staticdocs$
```

not

```
staticdocs
```

Comment: Thanks Hadley! Knew it would be a stupid mistake on my end by couldn't uncover it

Answer (score 4):

You should remove `inst/doc/`. All vignettes are supposed to be under `vignettes/` only. Another thing to keep in minds is that you should only keep source documents under `vignettes`, and all generated files should not be there, e.g. the HTML output. Although it is certainly not the best example, you can always check how **knitr** builds [its own vignettes](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/tree/master/vignettes).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Yihui. As per my recent edit, it turns out R CMD is re-creating the `inst/doc` directory, but not including the rendered file there. Any clue as to what's going on?