# R CMD build fails to ignore vignette referenced in .Rbuildignore

Tags: r, knitr

I have a vignette that I want to exclude from a build. Yes, I could delete it, but I think .Rbuildignore is supposed to help me here. I referenced the file in .Rbuildignore and it does not end up in the package. However, R CMD check gives a warning:

```
 * checking 'build' directory ... WARNING
 Output(s) listed in 'build/vignette.rds' but not in package:
   'inst/doc/ignoreMe.pdf'
```

Here is a related question [R CMD build skips knitr/Rmd vignettes - "Output(s) listed in 'build/vignette.rds' but not in package"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24436928/r-cmd-build-skips-knitr-rmd-vignettes-outputs-listed-in-build-vignette-rds) only, I wanted the vignette ignored (and for it to not generate a warning when it is ignored). Is that possible?

This does not appear to be mentioned in the [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#index-_002eRbuildignore-file) index link to .Rbuildignore.

Why would I want to do this? My development cycle has version *n* getting polished off while version *n*+1 is in the works. This vignette is part of *n*+1 and .Rbuildignore helps me exclude everything else from that version.

Comment: What is the line from your `.Rbuildignore` file?

Comment: the relevant line just says 'ignoreMe' it does what I want--remove the vignette and related .R source files.

Comment: This turned out to be a bug in R. It is fixed in R 3.4.0. see https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=17246

Comment: apparently this didn't make it into 3.4.0. It should be in R-patched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in R. It is claimed to be fixed in R 3.4.1. see bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=17246.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I sorted it by removing the VignetteBuilder argument from the DESCRIPTION file. Not sure if this is also your case.

Comment: That's fine if you do not want any vignettes. But it prevents all vignettes from being built, not just the one I do not want to include.