# How to create an R Markdown vignette containing plotly graphics

Tags: r

I have an existing R package on CRAN (the `rms` package) for which I desire to add an html vignette created using R Markdown with RStudio.  I see most of what I need in the *Writing R Extensions* manual and at [How to get RStudio to automatically compile R Markdown Vignettes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372260/how-to-get-rstudio-to-automatically-compile-r-markdown-vignettes)

What is not obvious is that I want to use `plotly` functions to create interactive graphics.  Self-contained html files using this with RStudio work great but I don't know how to make sure such vignettes work with a CRAN submission, and how to set this up.

Comment: I'd check out [the plotly vignettes](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/tree/master/vignettes), though they don't build properly for me in RStudio.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried the following. I created an R markdown document (test.Rmd) in RStudio and put in the following.

````
## Testing interactive graphics

```{r}
library(highcharter)
library(ggplot2)

data(diamonds, economics_long, mpg, package = "ggplot2")
hchart(mpg, "scatter", x = displ, y = hwy, group = class)
```
````

Convert this 'test.Rmd' to 'test.md' and finally to 'test.html' by clicking on the  `Knit HTML` button in RStudio OR by running the following script in the console:

```
library(knitr)
knit("test.Rmd", tangle=F, encoding = "utf-8")
render("test.md",output_format=html_document())
```

This generates an html file with interactive graphics.

[image: hicharter-plot]

Yes. This is not `plotly` but `highcharter` is a nice R package that includes several interactive javascript plotting libraries and it's easy to use. It's also better documented than `rCharts` for example. The package maintainer is also friendly and responsive to queries. Install `highcharter` package here:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("jbkunst/highcharter")
```

Comment: I tried that nice approach with plotly but the plots did not come out.  I wonder what differs with highcharter.

Comment: I remember this approach did not work with `rCharts`. There was an option to add assets or something. Can't remember. It was a while back.